# Get details(Symbol, Icon, ...) of any EVM-compatible network

Tags: blockchain

Is there any *free* and *unlimited* external API-endpoint that returns the details of any **EVM-compatible** network containing its *Symbol*, *Icon URL*, ... **by providing the network chain ID**?

Answer (score 1):

not a perfect solution, but you could get EVM compatible chains name, id, currency and icon URL by parsing out HTML returned by this request: https://chainlist.org/?search=

And if you know chaidID (for instance 56), you can use this: https://chainlist.org/chain/56

[image]

Comment: I do have the chainID but don't know how I can access the icon from the second request you mentioned!

Comment: you can parse it out from HTML. Look for <a> element that has href="/chain/56". When you find it get embedded img element. It's src contains the icon URL. See the screenshot in the answer